# How can I display Custom Post type Custom Columns and its Content in a Dashboard Widget?

Tags: php, plugin-development, widgets, dashboard

I am using the below two functions to add and show the Columns Content for the Custom Post in my Plugin

```
    add_filter("manage_{$this->post_slug}_posts_columns", array($this, 'browseColumns'));
add_action("manage_{$this->post_slug}_posts_custom_column", array($this, 'browseCustomColumns'), 10, 2);

 public function browseColumns($columns) {
$new = array();
foreach ($columns as $key => $title) {
    if ($key == 'date') {
    $new['wp_type'] = __('Type', self::$lang_slug);
    $new['wp_cost'] = __('Cost', self::$lang_slug);
    }
    $new[$key] = $title;
}
return $new;
}

   public function browseCustomColumns($column, $post_id) {
switch ($column) {
    case 'wp_type' :
    $type = get_post_meta($post_id, '_wp_type', true);
    echo empty($type) ? '-' : (int) $type;
    break;
    case 'wp_cost' :
    $cost = PluginClass::getCost($post_id);
    echo empty($cost) ? '-' : (int) $cost;
    break;

}
}
```

Below is the code for adding a Dashboard Widget for the Custom Plugin

```
/*
 *
 * Add a widget to the dashboard.
 *
 * This function is hooked into the 'add_dashboard_setup' action below.
 */

add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', array($this, 'add_dashboard_widget'));

  public function add_dashboard_widget() {
    add_meta_box('idx_dashboard_widget', 'WP WebinarSystem', array($this, 'compile_dashboard_widget'), 'dashboard', 'normal', 'high' );
}

/*
 *
 * Function to output the contents of our Dashboard Widget.
 *
 */
public function compile_dashboard_widget()
{
    echo $this->dashboard_widget_html();
    $this->loadPluginScripts();
    $this->loadFrontScripts();
}

public function dashboard_widget_html()
{


}
```

I want to display the Type and Cost Columns for my Custom Post into the Dashboard Widget.

I want to know if there are any hooks available in order to reuse or should I proceed writing the html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your specific question: no, there are no hooks that would allow you to "reuse".  However, there is nothing
keeping you from calling your `browseCustomColumns()` function in your function that renders the dashboard widget.
However, in order to do that, you'd have to make a minor change your `compile_dashboard_widget()` function:

```
public
function
compile_dashboard_widget ()
{
    // removed the call to echo, just call $this->dashboard_widget_html () and have
    // $this->dashboard_widget_html () do all the echo'ing
    $this->dashboard_widget_html () ;
    $this->loadPluginScripts () ;
    $this->loadFrontScripts () ;

    return ;
}

public
function
dashboard_widget_html ()
{
    global $post ;

    $args = array (
        'post_type' => $this->post_slug,
        // any other WP_Query args you want
        ) ;
    $posts = new WP_Query ($args) ;

    if ($posts->has_posts ()) {
        while ($posts->has_posts ()) {
            $posts->the_post () ;

            // you'd probably want addition markup here
            // (e.g., a table, which each post in a <tr> and title/type/cost as <td>)
            // but you can figure out how you want your dashboard widget to look
            the_title () ;

            $this->browseCustomColumns ('wp_type', $post->ID) ;
            $this->browseCustomColumns ('wp_cost', $post->ID) ;
            }
        }
    else {
        echo 'no custom posts' ;
        }

    wp_reset_postdata () ;

    return ;
}
```

Hope this helps.